# Distributing $n\leq r$ different things among $r$ distinct persons when each person can get at most $1$ thing.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many combinations are there when we want to distribute $n\leq r$ different things among $r$ distinct persons, when each person may only get $1$ thing.

(For example we want to distribute $3$ different colors among $5$ different persons and each person may only get one color at most)

For the case $n=r$ there should be $n!$ many combinations, since the first thing can go to all $n=r$ persons, the next thing may only choose from $n-1$ persons, and so on.

But how does this continue for $n<r$ objects. For $2$ objects and $3$ persons we would get $6$ combinations according to the attached picture of mine. [image: three_persons_two_objects]

Comment: You say each person can get only one "thing", but your diagram shows some person(s) getting $2$ ??

Comment: @trueblueanil - I think you should read each row as a possible allocation, so one person gets item 1 and another person gets item 2 and the third gets nothing, with 6 rows and so 6 possible allocations.  It is not difficult to see that the answer is $r!$ when $n=r-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your perspective a bit. Instead distributing n objects among r people, first choose n people and distribute the objects among those. You have shown that you know how to handle the case if n=r. The question now is, how many ways can you choose n people from a total of r? You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Isn't it then just ${r \choose n}\cdot n!$?

Comment: Yup, you could even simplify it down to $\frac{r!}{(r-n)!}$.